# Sporadic SqlException Class 11 Number 0 (serious error)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL-Server 11.0.3128.0 for some time now and usually it just works.

For some strange reason today I start to get SqlExceptions when trying to read from a SqlDataReader using code which did not change for weeks now. And it's not only me, a customer is having the very same problems.

I'm a bit at a loss how to debug this, since the error message is useless for me. The code is reading from a SqlDataReader when the exception occurs:

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReaderWithEx())
{
  while (rdr.Read())  // <-- the SqlException happens here
  {
    nAllQueryRows = (int)rdr["TotalRowCount"];
    rc.Add(new Datenkey(tabelleID, (long)rdr[1]));
  }
}
```

The SQL-Command is a a search across several databases and views:

```
WITH NumberedList AS 
(
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Artikel_View].[Key]) AS [RowNum]
 ,[Artikel_View].[Key] 
 ,COUNT(*) OVER () AS [TotalRowCount]
 FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[Artikel_View]
  WHERE (([Artikel_View].[GeloeschtAm] IS NULL)
 AND (EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[Artikel] WHERE [Artikel_View].[Key] = [Artikel].[Key] AND CONTAINS(*, '"steril"'))
  OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[ArtikelLieferanten] WHERE [Artikel_View].[Key] = [ArtikelLieferanten].[ArtikelKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"steril"'))
  OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[ArtikelLager] WHERE [Artikel_View].[Key] = [ArtikelLager].[ArtikelKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"steril"'))
  OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[ArtikelVKPreise] WHERE [Artikel_View].[Key] = [ArtikelVKPreise].[ArtikelKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"steril"'))
  OR EXISTS (SELECT [Key] FROM [MyDatabase].dbo.[KundenReservierteBestaende] WHERE [Artikel_View].[Key] = [KundenReservierteBestaende].[ArtikelKey] AND CONTAINS(*, '"steril"'))))
 AND  (([Artikel_View].[Nr] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[KatalogNr] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[PZN] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Hilfsmittelpositionsnummer1] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[HerstellerNr] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Suchwort1] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Suchwort2] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Suchwort3] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Suchwort4] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[BezeichnungKurz] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.Nr] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.NameVorname] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.KuerzelFuerArtikelNr] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.Suchwort1] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.Suchwort2] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.Suchwort3] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.Suchwort4] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lieferanten.LieferantKey.UnsereKdNrBeiLieferant] LIKE @suchwort1a)
 OR ([Artikel_View].[Lager.StandardLagerplatzKey.Kuerzel] LIKE @suchwort1a))
)
SELECT * FROM NumberedList WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 100 ORDER BY [Key]
```

The query has two parameters (yes, the second one is never been used - I'll try to get rid of it):

```
@suchwort1a='plast%'
@suchwort1c='%[^A-z^Ä^Ö^Ü^ä^ö^ü^ß]plast%'
```

It throws an SqlException Class 11 Number 0 LineNumber 0 with the (german) text "Für den aktuellen Befehl ist ein schwerwiegender Fehler aufgetreten. Löschen Sie eventuelle Ergebnisse." (in english something like "severe error in current command. Discard results").

The error does happen a lot at the customers site but only a few times on my Debugging System. I got no idea what this error is trying to tell me. For me it seems like SQL Server has an internal hiccup. If I rerun the very same SQL command it will usually work, so it seems to be some fleeting internal condition of the Server causing the error.

How can I solve this problem?

[Update] The SQL Server Error Log contains a dump of the state:

```
2014-05-22 14:00:42.48 spid51      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.BSOFT\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0003.txt
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 3772 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *   05/22/14 14:00:42 spid 3772
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *   Exception Address = 00007FFA87046E07 Module(sqllang+0000000000BB6E07)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *   Access Violation occurred reading address 000000081C1A4000
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * Input Buffer 255 bytes -
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *                     16 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[... lots of bytes...]
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *  a s t %            61 00 73 00 74 00 25 00
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * sqlservr                       00007FF79E580000  00007FF79E5BDFFF  0003e000
[... lots of modules...]
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * dbghelp                        000000005C1F0000  000000005C385FFF  00196000
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P1Home: 0000000000000018:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P2Home: 0000000000000004:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P3Home: 000000081C1A4000:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P4Home: 000000081C1A02B8:  0000524400000001  0000000000000100  000000087D1F8040  0000000000015250  000000084B494040  0000000000000001  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P5Home: 0000000021FCD580:  0000000000000004  0000000821F4B070  0000000821F4A9D0  0000000000000000  0000000821F2A301  0000000821F4B070  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     P6Home: 0000000021FCD610:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      * ContextFlags: 000000000010005F:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA0:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegCs: 0000000000000033:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegDs: 000000000000002B:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegEs: 000000000000002B:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegFs: 0000000000000053:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegGs: 000000000000002B:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *      SegSs: 000000000000002B:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *     EFlags: 0000000000010216:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rax: 0000000000000000:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rcx: 00007FFA87046E31:  EBC09F0F30533B49  C09E0F30533B4910  9D0F30533B4907EB  48C7FF0B75C084C0  AEEB08C38348C6FF  5E73F93B410A8B45  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rdx: 000000081C1A3070:  0000081000000000  0000000000000F60  000000081C1A3FE0  000000081C1A3FE0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rbx: 000000081C1A4000:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rsp: 0000000021FCDBF8:  00007FFA87046C17  0000000821F4AD50  0000000821F4AD00  0000000000000000  0000000821F4B070  000000081C197831  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rbp: 00007FFA86490000:  0000000300905A4D  0000FFFF00000004  00000000000000B8  0000000000000040  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rsi: 0000000000000608:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        Rdi: 0000000000000608:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *         R8: 0000000000000000:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *         R9: 0000000000000004:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        R10: 0000000821F4B070:  000000080000003C  000000081C197720  0000000821F0ED00  0000000821F0ED60  000000081C1A0FC0  000000081C1A11E0  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        R11: 0000000821F4A9D0:  00007FFA86BA1158  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000800000000  0000000821F56040  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        R12: 0000000000000000:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        R13: 0000000821F2A301:  600000000821F0F4  000000000821F643  E000000000000000  9000007FFA888E22  C000007FFA888E22  0000007FFA888E22  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.49 spid51      *        R14: 0000000821F4B070:  000000080000003C  000000081C197720  0000000821F0ED00  0000000821F0ED60  000000081C1A0FC0  000000081C1A11E0  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      *        R15: 8000000000000001:  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      *        Rip: 00007FFA87046E07:  7705F98341138B48  D8858C8BC1634949  E1FFCD034800BB6E  EBC0940F30533B49  C09C0F30533B4922  9F0F30533B4919EB  
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      * Short Stack Dump
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA87046E07 Module(sqllang+0000000000BB6E07)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA87046C17 Module(sqllang+0000000000BB6C17)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA870375CF Module(sqllang+0000000000BA75CF)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA8702F22B Module(sqllang+0000000000B9F22B)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA87015C72 Module(sqllang+0000000000B85C72)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA87017DF4 Module(sqllang+0000000000B87DF4)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA86FE87EA Module(sqllang+0000000000B587EA)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA87029FF6 Module(sqllang+0000000000B99FF6)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA8702BF94 Module(sqllang+0000000000B9BF94)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA86F7A117 Module(sqllang+0000000000AEA117)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA86D10A7D Module(sqllang+0000000000880A7D)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA890E643B Module(sqlmin+0000000000BC643B)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA88568EF7 Module(sqlmin+0000000000048EF7)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA88649D62 Module(sqlmin+0000000000129D62)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA886466D2 Module(sqlmin+00000000001266D2)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA886481B1 Module(sqlmin+00000000001281B1)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA88707952 Module(sqlmin+00000000001E7952)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA85793D80 Module(sqldk+0000000000013D80)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA85793B64 Module(sqldk+0000000000013B64)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA85793967 Module(sqldk+0000000000013967)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA857B2F0F Module(sqldk+0000000000032F0F)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA857B3750 Module(sqldk+0000000000033750)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.50 spid51      00007FFA857B2C5D Module(sqldk+0000000000032C5D)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.51 spid51      00007FFA857B3F88 Module(sqldk+0000000000033F88)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.51 spid51      00007FFA916116AD Module(KERNEL32+00000000000016AD)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.51 spid51      00007FFA937F4629 Module(ntdll+0000000000074629)
2014-05-22 14:00:42.53 spid51      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000014CD388CE
2014-05-22 14:00:43.25 spid51      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
```

Comment: What does error log say?

Comment: What's `cmd.ExecuteReaderWithEx()`? It's not a framework method.

Comment: Ah sorry, I added ExecuteReaderWithEx() to debug, it's a small helper method which executing the command with try/catch and logging exceptions:
`public static SqlDataReader ExecuteReaderWithEx(this SqlCommand cmd)
{
  try
  {
    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
    Logger.LogSqlException(ex);
    throw;
  }
}`

Comment: @st4hoo there is no related message in the windows event logs - or do you refer to some other error log?

Comment: @st4hoo, I found the SQL Server error logs, they contain Information, but for me not very useful. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: The main message in the error log is: "spid51      SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 10204 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process."

Answer (score 0):

Are you running SQL 2005?  This sounds like this bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938102

Comment: Looks really like that bug, but it's SQL-Server 2012, to be exact version 11.0.3128.0 (I'll add the Version to the question, thanks for the reminder)